# TableModel - Doesn`t show anything in the gui?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel, listselectionlistener

I am fetching the data from the DAO to the GUI level.

When I want to load the Table I get an empty table only with the right row count of the clicked db symbol:

[image]

To load the elements I use:

```
playlistTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
        JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int row = target.getSelectedRow();
        playlistTableModel.setPlaylists(playlistService.getMoviesOfPlaylist(row));
}
```

Why is the Table empty?

**UPDATE**

Table model code:

```
public class PlaylistTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    /**
     * Generated UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9058516120594137393L;


    /**
     * List of playlist to be shown
     */
    private List<Playlist> playlist;

    public PlaylistTableModel(List<Playlist> playlist){
        this.playlist=playlist;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return playlist.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        Playlist playlists = playlist.get(arg0);
        switch(arg1){
        case 0: return playlists.getName();
        default: return null;
        }
    }    

    public void setPlaylists(List<Playlist> playlist){
        this.playlist=playlist;
        fireTableDataChanged();//Aktualisiert Playlist automatisch
    }

    public void setPlaylist(Playlist playlists){
        playlist.add(playlists);
        fireTableRowsInserted(playlist.size()-1, playlist.size()-1);
    }


    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        if(column==0){
            return "Playlist";
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a movie from the list specified by the index
     * @param row index of the movie
     * @return movie
     */
    public Playlist getPlaylist(int row){
        return playlist.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
        if(columnIndex!=0){
            return;
        }    
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
```

Comment: have you tried repainting after the call?

Comment: Right now I am repainting it after teh action(see mouse listener)

Comment: I mean, try and call repaint()

Comment: Yep...but does not make a difference...

Comment: There it no way to help, unless you show the code of your table model .

Comment: Having a `List<Playlist>` called `playlist`, and referring to a single Playlist instance as `playlists` is very confusing. Why do you use the plural form for a single instance, and the singular form for multiple instances? Similarly why call `setPlaylist()` a method which *adds* a playlist?

Comment: Give the fact that you seem to be getting rows, either the `playlist` has no name or the cell renderer is using the background color as the text color

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method may be the problem,

```
public void setPlaylist(Playlist playlists){
    playlist.add(playlists);
    fireTableRowsInserted(playlist.size()-1, playlist.size()-1);
}
```

Here for example if we got the playlists with size 20. Then after assigning to the table model playlist you are calling,

```
fireTableRowsInserted(playlist.size()-1, playlist.size()-1);
```

which will reduce to,

```
fireTableRowsInserted(19, 19);
```

But actually what has happened is we are not just inserting one row but 20 rows. So as suggested by [@Ivan.Latysh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778561/tablemodel-doesnt-show-anything-in-the-gui) in the answer section, you need to call insert from the start of the row count to the end of the row count. This will `repaint` the inserted rows.

**P.S:** You can simply call `fireTableDataChanged();` method also. But this method will `repaint` entire table. Prefer this method only if the entire table list is changed. Else you have respective `fireXX` methods for [Insertion, Update, Delete.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably issue is in `getValueAt` method, change like this

```
 public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // since you use only one column     
        return playlist.get(arg0).getName();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are firing a wrong change event

```
fireTableRowsInserted(playlist.size()-1, playlist.size()-1);
```

Docs state:

```
public void fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow,
                              int lastRow)

Notifies all listeners that rows in the range [firstRow, lastRow], inclusive, have been inserted.
```

So if you want to be optimal, do this:

```
public void setPlaylist(Playlist playlists){
  int firstRow = playlist.size();
  playlist.add(playlists);
  fireTableRowsInserted(firstRow, playlist.size()-1);
}
```

Or simply re-draw entire table. Don't forget that table also may re-calculate its sizes.

```
fireTableDataChanged();
```